# How to create dynamic gradle tasks based on list of strings

Tags: gradle, groovy

I see this example of dynamic Gradle tasks on various sites:

```
4.times { counter ->
task "task$counter" << {
    println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

I would like to create dynamic tasks based on a list of strings such as:

```
def taskSuffixes = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

taskSuffixes.each { it ->
    task t_$it << {
        println "My name is: $it"
        }
    }
```

However, that does not seem to work. Is this possible? If it is not possible, what would be a good alternative given that my list will be strings and I will eventually need those strings within the matching task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put double quotes round your templated string

```
task "t_$it" << {
    println "My name is: $it"
}
```

`<<` was deprecated around Gradle 4, the new way is to use `doLast`

```
task "t_$it" {
    doLast {
        println "My name is: $it"
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun!

Comment: This answer is outdated. You no longer need to use the `<<` operator in order to define the dynamic task as outlined in the documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:dynamic_tasks